# utf-8 and ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, actionmailer

I'm facing some problems with UTF-8 and ActionMailer. My application has a form (contact) that when it is submitted, it sends an email to me. The problem is that when somebody enters some chars like öäüß, I receive the message encoded like for example

```
 =?UTF-8?Q?funktioniert_oder_nicht.=0D=0A=0D=0Ameine_Stra=C3=9Fe_ist_die?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_Bratwurststra=C3=9Fe=0D=0A=0D=0A=C3=B6=C3=A4?=
```

As I understand, ActionMailer per default is utf-8 ready. Analyzing the log from my server, when the form is submitted, the params are already well encoded (it means I can read the äüö in my log)

Any idea about what should I change? should I change my application to support ISO-8859-1?

environment: ruby 1.9 and rails 3.1

Comment: Ruby 1.8 or 1.9? 1.9 should do the unicode handling for you.

Comment: try to set `# coding: utf-8` at the top of actionmailer view

Comment: it is already. The web server log shows me that the params are UTF-8, i think the problem is related with the mailer configuration itself.

Comment: sure it's not just the rails console not displaying utf-8 correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the UTF-8 bytes escaped with [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

ß is "\xC3\x9F" -> "=C3=9F"

[`String#unpack('M')`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack) will decode it:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "Bratwurststra=C3=9Fe=0D=0A=0D=0A=C3=B6=C3=A4".unpack "M"'
Bratwurststraße

öä
```

`