# ActionMailer in Ruby on Rails breaks when given an email address that has special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer to send emails, it works when given a normal email address, here is my code snippet

```
logger = Logger.new('logfile.log')
logger.info(@user.email)
mail(
  charset: "UTF-8",
  to: @user.email,
  from: @from,
  subject: @subject
)
```

in the log it shows the email address just fine with special characters.
but then I go to my development log and see this in the mail object, everything else is right

`To: =?UTF-8?B?w7FAw7EuY29tPg==?=`

I've tried to wrap it in quotes and using a different format like so:

`("\"#{@user.name}\" <#{@user.email}>")`

which translates to:

`"name name" <test_ñ@yahoo.com>`

no luck on these either, I just get a similar gibberish

`=?UTF-8?Q?=22name_name=22_<test=5F=C3=B1@yahoo.com>?=`

also tried to use `"test_ñ"@yahoo.com`

same results:

`=?UTF-8?Q?=22test=5F=C3=B1=22@yahoo.com>?=`

what am I missing here? is it something with encoding configs?

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem? Have you viewed this email in a mail client? It's been a while since I worked with email on this level, but that looks like it is encoding the field.  The special chars NEED to be encoded, because SMTP only deals with plain text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [utf-8 and ActionMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430940/utf-8-and-actionmailer)

Comment: ah I actually thought about that, but I did test this in a live environment, any  addresses that has special characters never gets sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not gibberish. That's MIME encoding ([RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)). Everything's fine.

You can paste that line in [MIME online decoder](http://dogmamix.com/MimeHeadersDecoder/) and ensure it decodes to `To: my_user@exampl.com` (email address redacted).

Comment: ah... so, somewhere in my code it's reading the 'gibberish' as plaintext email address and not decoding it I'm guessing

Comment: Why you need to read and decode your email address? ActionMailer handles encoding/decoding automatically, you don't need to mess with it, unless you have specific purpose. If you see that encoded field in console/logs – it's fine, it is supposed to be there.

Comment: then why is the email not sending? caused by an unrelated issue?

Comment: Yup. You should ask exactly what do you want from the beginning :)

Comment: thank you so much! I will go back to digging. Also, can you please remove that email address from your answer? it's probably not a real email address but just to be safe. thanks! I will remove the gibberish from my question as well.

Comment: Well, if you are satisfied with my explanation, you should accept an answer, and then start another question describing your real problem.